# How to initialize an array in nasm?

Tags: assembly, nasm

What I am trying to init is an array like this:

```
int array_int[10] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
```

and my nasm code is:

```
array_int db 1, times 3 db 0, 2, times 3 db 0, 3, times 3 db 0, db 4, times 1Bh db 0
```

the assembler just output:

```
error: expression syntax error
```

Could any one give me some help? 
Thank you!

Comment: Isn't it array_int dword 1, 2, 3, 4 ?

Comment: @BlackBear closer, but not quite: that would give an array of 4 elements. The OP needs an array of 10 elements where the first 4 are pre-initialized.

Comment: "int" sort of implies `dword`, no? I think `array_int dd 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0` might do what you want. If you want to use `times`, put each `times` on a new line and Nasm will probably eat it.

Answer (score 2):

Given your attempt:

```
array_int db 1, times 3 db 0, 2, times 3 db 0, ...
```

it looks like you have a 32-bit little-endian architecture so there are a couple of ways to do this.

The first is the rather verbose:

```
array_int  db  1, 0, 0, 0  ; a[0]
           db  2, 0, 0, 0  ; a[1]
           db  3, 0, 0, 0  ; a[2]
           db  4, 0, 0, 0  ; a[3]
           db  0, 0, 0, 0  ; a[4]
           db  0, 0, 0, 0  ; a[5]
           db  0, 0, 0, 0  ; a[6]
           db  0, 0, 0, 0  ; a[7]
           db  0, 0, 0, 0  ; a[8]
           db  0, 0, 0, 0  ; a[9]
```

The second is to realise that `dd` can be used for defining 32-bit values without figuring out the `db` layout manually:

```
array_int  dd  1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
```

Comment: _"it looks like you have a 32-bit big-endian architecture"_ Seems unlikely, since NASM is an x86 assembler.

Comment: Sorry, @Michael, bit of a brain-fart, I of course _meant_ little-endian. Fixed now.